# invalid expression, assumed zero must be a constant expression

Tags: pawn

```
(1204) : error 029: invalid expression, assumed zero
(1204 -- 1205) : error 008: must be a constant expression; assumed zero

     (1203)    "{CCFF99}[INFO]:{FFFFFF} Nu uita sa faci poza la {CCFF99}/stats{FFFFFF} periodic.",
     (1204) }
     (1205) new rCheckList[sizeof(rMessageList)];
```

Please help me idk what to do :c,this is in pawn..

Answer (score 0):

solved it had to put }; and remove the , from 1203